# hyperbolic-function, improper integration and uniform convergence.

Tags: improper-integrals, uniform-convergence, hyperbolic-functions

Define
$$I(t) := \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \cosh(tx) dx , \quad J(t) := \int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2}\sinh(tx) dx.$$

**question**

(1)Both $I(t)$ and $J(t)$ uniformly converge on $[0, R)\quad (R>0).$

(2)Calculate $I(t)$.

**attempt**
(1)I know the definition of uniform convergence of improper integral. I tried finding $g$ that satisfies $(i)e^{-x^2} \cosh(tx) \leq g(x)$, and $(ii) g $ is improper integrable. But I could not, because $\cosh(tx)$ grows forever.

(2)I could calculate $I(0)$, because $I(0) = \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$. And I think integration by parts repetition may help.

**edit**

I understand (2).

It holds

$$I(t) = \frac{1}{2}I^\prime(t),$$

so the rest is easy.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \cosh(tx) dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} e^{tx} dx ; -x^2+tx=-(x-t/2)^2+t^2/4$. Then, make substitution $y=x-t/2; dx=dy$

Comment: I tried it, but $\int_0^\infty e^{\frac{t^2}{4}} dx$ is not integrable.

Comment: For $x \geqslant 0$ and $0 \leqslant t < R$, we have

$$|e^{-x^2} \cosh (tx)| = e^{-x^2}\frac{e^{tx} + e^{-tx}}{2} \leqslant \frac{1}{2}(e^{Rx} + 1) e^{-x^2} = g(x)$$ and $g$ is integrable over $[0,\infty)$.  This is the Weierstrass test for improper integrals.

Comment: @RRL, thank you for your kindness!